# Matlab - Opening more then one image extension - working with images

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I need open and put in the same vector .jpg images and .bmp images.
I can open or .jpg or .bmp, but i need to open both.

This is my code:

```
    image_folder = 'C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\teste';    
    filenames = dir(fullfile(image_folder, '*.jpg')); 
    total_images = numel(filenames); 

    for n=1:total_images
    images{n} = imread(sprintf('color%03d.jpg',n));  
    end;
```

(in this example i open jpgs but i need to open .jpg And .bmp     )

Comment: i tried something like

for n=1:total_images2
            images2{n} = imread(sprintf('cor%03d.jpg',n));
        end

But i don't know how to put together images1{n} and images2{n}

Answer (score 0):

`filenames = dir()` should give you the filenames you need to cycle through; you shouldn't have to parse the bmp from jpg files. If the directory only contains images you want to you can try something like:

```
imageFolder = 'C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\teste\';
filenames = dir(imageFolder);

numImages = length(filenames)-2; % exclude counting '.' and '..'
images = cell(numImages,1);

n = 1;
for i = 1:length(filenames)
    if filenames(i).name(1) ~= '.'
        images{n} = imread([imageFolder filenames(i).name]);
        n = n+1;
    end
end
```